# Is it possible to draw rectangles based on an integer array?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a level system in Swing for my game (personal purposes only). I've been thinking of using an integer array, something like this :

```
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

where the `1`s are the rectangles to draw. The width and height would be fixed, but X and Y would vary from the position of the `1`s of the array. I've been trying something like this :

```
for (int num : grid)
    {
        if (num == 1)
        {
            x += 100;
            y -= 100;
            objects.add(new GameObject(1, x, y, 250, 25, Color.white));
        }
    }
```

But it completely fails. The GameObject constructor parameters are `id, x, y, width, height, color` respectively. I'm also using Graphics2D, if that helps.

How would this be done?

Comment: Create an ArrayList of Rectangle objects. Then in the paintComponent() method you iterate through the ArrayList and paint each object. See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach. In your case you just manually add the rectangle to the ArrayList.

Comment: I get it, but how would you use like a 0 1 grid or at least a number grid instead of a whole object? (If it's possible)

Comment: Instead of using Rectangles, you could use a Point object to indicate which grid should contain a rectangle..

Comment: You have a 20 x 10 grid.  If each rectangle was 100 x 100 pixels, your drawing area would have to be 2,000 x 1,000 pixels.  Everyone doesn't have a 4K monitor.  Make your grid a two-dimensional int array,  Iterate through the rows and columns, creating a GameObject for every 1 you find.

Comment: "I've been thinking of using an integer array, something like this" Why though? Isn't it simpler to just keep a list of all objects and their positions?

Comment: It might be simpler to add the GameObjects, but it would be more efficient to use numbers for the simplicity of just creating new platforms and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)<sup>1</sup> of what I think you are trying tp produce:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTestPanel extends JPanel{

    private static final int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 10, STEP = 25;
    private int numberOfRectangles = 0;
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static int[][] grid = {
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        };

    public SwingTestPanel()  {
        setLayout(null);
        int x = 0, y = 0; numberOfRectangles = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++){
                 if (grid[i][j] == 1){
                      shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
                      x += STEP;  y += STEP; numberOfRectangles++;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        int width = WIDTH + STEP * numberOfRectangles;
        int height = HEIGHT +  STEP * numberOfRectangles;
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for(Shape shape : shapes){
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.fill(shape);
        }
         g2d.dispose();
         g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new SwingTestPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(run it on-line [here](https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/PinkSereneUtilities))

The `grid` matrix is not really used here. The `0` values are not used and the indices of the `1` values are not used. 
The only useful information in this big matrix is the number of `1` values (16 in this example), so the same result can be achieved with:

```
public class SwingTestPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 10, STEP = 25;
    private final int numberOfRectangles = 16;
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public SwingTestPanel()  {
        setLayout(null);
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRectangles; i++){
            shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            x += STEP;  y += STEP;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        int width = WIDTH + STEP * numberOfRectangles;
        int height = HEIGHT +  STEP * numberOfRectangles;
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for(Shape shape : shapes){
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.fill(shape);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new SwingTestPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(run it on-line [here](https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/SadTechnoEngineering))

If the index information is needed for the offset, store just it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTestPanel extends JPanel{

    private static final int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 10, STEP = 100;
    private int maxX = 0, maxY = 0;
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static int[][] offesetts = {
            {0,8},
            {0,9},
            {0,10},
            {0,11},
            {2,5},
            {2,6},
            {2,7},
            {3,11},
            {5,5},
            {5,6},
            {5,7},
            {7,0},
            {7,1},
            {7,2},
            {7,3},
            {7,4}
    };

    public SwingTestPanel()  {
        setLayout(null);
        for(int[] offset : offesetts){
            int x = offset[1]*STEP;
            int y = offset[0]*STEP;
            maxX = x+WIDTH > maxX ? x+WIDTH : maxX;
            maxY = y+HEIGHT > maxY ? y+HEIGHT : maxY;
            shapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(x,y, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(maxX, maxY);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for(Shape shape : shapes){
            g2d.draw(shape);
            g2d.fill(shape);
        }
         g2d.dispose();
         g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new SwingTestPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

(run it on-line [here](https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/AvariciousWellmadeExtraction))

---

<sup>1</sup> Always consider posting mre when asking or answering

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create a two dimensional `int` grid array, your code could look something like this:

```
        int[][] grid = new int[10][20];
        
        int id = 1;
        int width = 25;
        int spacing = 50;
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {
                if (grid[y][x] == 1) {
                    objects.add(new GameObject(id++, x * spacing, y * spacing, 
                            width, width, Color.white));
                 }
            }
        }
```

where `width` is the width and height of the game object and `spacing` is how far apart the game objects are.